# onpause mediaplayer from activity

Tags: android

I've an activity with preferences: enable/disable sound and enable/disable sound background. Reading sharepreferences I start a service that starts mediaplayer. I need pause mediaplayer when activity goes in `onPause()` state.

Activity:

```
// reading sharedpreferences, if true:
    startService(new Intent(this, UnUsedService.class));
```

service:

```
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    player.start();

};
```

Answer (score 1):

I dunno whether these solution is correct or not. But you can definitely give it a try.

**A.** `Binding` and `Unbinding` Service at `onPause()` and `onResume()`

`Acitivity` should `unBind` to Service at `onPause()` of Activity, but if you didn't call an `unbind ()`, I think you will get a memory leak.

`Activity` should `reBind` to Service at `onResume()` of Activity. But These binding unbinding may cause you `NullPointerException`

---

**B**. `Sending BroadCastReceiver` may build you something like that.

***Register and Unregister Broadcast on your needs***

***Inside Your Activity-onPause()***

```
String PAUSE_MUSIC="PAUSE_MUSIC_INSIDE_SERVICE";
Intent intent = new Intent(PAUSE_MUSIC_INSIDE_SERVICE);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

***Inside Your Service***

```
BroadCastReceiver receiver=new PauseMusicReceiver(); 
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Activity.PAUSE_MUSIC);
getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

class PauseMusicReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
  {
     //Pause your MediaPlayer
   }
}
```

---

**C**. `Sleep or Suspend Thread which is created at Service`

***Media inside Service is also handle with the thread you created for Service. So may be suspending or putting that Thread to Sleep Mode at onPause() of Activity and resuming that Thread again at onResume() of Activity can help.***

***Thread methods -onSuspend(), onStart(), onResume(), onSleep()***